# How to customize gmail subject by using python

Tags: python, gmail-api, mime

I want to style gmail subject header while sending email using python. I am using python `email.mime.text`. There are quite many solutions that covers for styling the message body by using `mime.MultiPart` but I cannot find for styling the subject. In below code, I want to style for the subject.

```
        message = MIMEText(msg_body)
        message['To'] = to 
        message['From'] = sender  
        message['Subject'] = subject

        message = {'message': {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode(),
                               'threadId': threadId}}
```

Any idea, how to do it ?

Comment: Can message _subject_ even be styled? I never encountered an email like that. You can use emoji in it, though, and maybe other interesting Unicode characters; I've seen this in emails I received, and Gmail shows them correctly. Those are regular Unicode characters, usable inside a Python string literal.

Comment: @9000 yea thats what I checking , i didnt find anything like that. So, I was wondering if it is even possible ? for example here it covers a lot of information, but nothing related to styling the subject, https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html

Comment: I think email subject is always plain text. It is the _body_ where you can provide different variants using MIME, so you can provide a HTML-formatted body, attach images, etc. The subject is one and the same for all formatting variants.

Comment: @9000 I wanted to give some kind of styling (to let know that this has been sent by using gmail api ) without opening the email. Styling the content wont be seen without opening the email. Is there anyway that can be highlighted the email to let know that this is sent by using gmail api (without opening email)? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot style an email subject.

An email subject is a plain text string, [defined by RFC-2822 as a text field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.5). Any markup you might add to it will be rendered as is, not interpreted.

Email *body* is a different thing, in a MIME-formatted email it may come in multiple formats, including `text/html`, which would be rendered as HTML by a client that knows how to do so (e.g. Gmail).

If you want to embellish your email's subject, add emoji characters or other Unicode characters:

`Happy New Year! ❄❄❄`

These are going to be rendered by Unicode-capable clients (again, such as Gmail).

Comment: thanks. I found this links https://customer.io/blog/gmail-grid-view-what-to-know-emails/  (Preheader text is eliminated) this should do the tricks. But I don't know if there is any implementation in python for creating such in gmail.

Comment: "Pre-header text" is just the beginning of your email. Gmail specifically has a "grid view" that formats the list of the emails differently, and can show pictures. OTOH that view appears to only be available in the "Promotions" tab, and I failed to find a way to switch the normal inbox to it at all. If you're sending promotional emails, address Gmail specifically, and suppose that your users will read it in the "Promotions" tab, then yes, the article above will help!